# Bash list files that has numerical pattern bigger then a value

Tags: bash

If I have in my directory several files such as the following:
1.zip
2.zip
3.zip
4.zip
11.zip
21.zip

Using bash, how do I list/find a file that has number in their name > 10 for example?

will give me 11.zip and 21.zip

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
for f in *.zip; do (( ${f%.*} > 10 )) && echo "$f"; done

11.zip
21.zip
```

`${f%.*}` will strip extension from your filename and `(( ${f%.*} > 10 ))` will return true only if remaining part is greater than `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended globbing, for example:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
echo @(1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]).zip
```

The `@` indicates exactly one of the patterns in the parentheses.  This will match filenames between 11 and 99 followed by ".zip".

EDIT:  To avoid "noise" as pointed out by @RonPringadi

Comment: I think this would work too but if there is no match  it will print out some noise

[root@test tmp]# echo @(1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]).zip
11.zip 12.zip
[root@test tmp]# echo @(2[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]).zip
@(2[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]).zip

Comment: @RonPringadi:  `shopt -s nullglob`